# Is the following argument invalid or how do we call this type of argument with contradictory truth values of its premises?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am not sure if this argument is also called as an invalid argument:

Premis1: $\neg a \to \neg b$ (true), Premis2: $a$ (true), Premis3: $b$ (true)

Comment: Note that the premises are not inconsistent.  If $a$ is true, so is premise 1.  The argument is incorrect because $b$ could be either true or false and premise 1 is still true

Comment: What argument??? You've stated three (non-contradictory) premises; what's the _conclusion_ of the "argument"?

Comment: @RossMillikan Looks like you didn't notice statement 3 is listed as a premise either ... :)

Comment: @Bram28 It wasn’t there when I commented

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, that explains a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I assume statement 3) is supposed to be the conclusion?

As such, this is called the [Fallacy of Denying the Antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent)

In this fallacy you typically go from $a \rightarrow b$ and $\neg a$ to $\neg b$, but it is easily understood that going from $\neg a \rightarrow \neg b$ and $a$ to $b$ is the same idea: you deny/oppose the antecedent (the 'íf'part of the conditional), in order to deny/oppose the consequent (the 'then' part of the conditional).

A related fallacy is the [Fallacy of Affirming the Consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent): going from $a \rightarrow b$ and $b$ to $a$. There, you affirm the consequent in order to affirm the antecedent.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Wow, I didn't notice that. I interpreted the third statement as a conclusion .... because it is such a common argument as such. A good example of constructive perception!

Comment: " A good example of constructive perception!" took me a minute to figure out what this meant, because "constructive" so often means something like "good" or "useful". I think I got it - here "constructive perception" refers to the fact that our perceptions are things we construct, not objective images of external reality, right? If so then yes it's a good example of that...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the argument is actually $\neg a \to \neg b, a \vdash b$, this is a bit obscured version of [denying the antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denying_the_antecedent). Example: "if something isn't a fruit, then it is not an orange": $a = \text{something is a fruit}$, $b = \text{something is an orange}$. Now, applying this "argument" to apple, we get: apple is a fruit, therefore apple is an orange.

Comment: I interpreted it as last premise is actually a conclusion.